# I have a List of checkboxes, how do I get their state

Tags: react-native

If I have a List in React Native and each list item has a checkbox, how can I get the state of all of those checkboxes?

Right now I’m using this

```
{
  this.props.data.allLogs.map((r) => {
    return (
      <ListItem
        key={r.id}
        title={r.logDate}
        onPress={() => this.toggle(r.id)}
        subtitle={
          <CheckBox
            title={`start: ${r.startedAtOdometerReading} -> end: ${r.endedAtOdometerReading}`}
            checked={this.state.checkboxes[r.id]}
            onPress={() => this.toggle(r.id)}
            onIconPress={() => this.toggle(r.id)}
          />
        }
      />
    );
  })
}




toggle(id) {
    let checkboxes = this.state.checkboxes;
    checkboxes[id] = !this.state.checkboxes[id];
    this.setState({checkboxes});
  }
```

and it works (checkboxes toggle on and off without a problem), but when I log out this.state.checkboxes I get an empty array…

Comment: Hard to give much guidance without more info on your setup, but you probably need to store the checked box state outside of the component, otherwise when you logout the component will unmount and state will be lost

Answer (score 3):

First of all, make sure you do NOT change the state directly as this is a bad practice in React, you should change your `toggle` function to this

```
toggle(id) {
    this.setState({checkboxes: {...this.state.checkboxes, [id]: !this.state.checkboxes[id]}});
}
```

Now to answer your question - it's hard to tell without the rest of the code but you can refactor it like this

```
class CheckboxesList extends React.Component {

    //...

    renderListElements = () => {
        const { checkboxes } = this.state
        this.props.data.allLogs.map((r) => {
            return (
                <CheckboxListItem
                    key={r.id}
                    toggle={this.toggle}
                    checked={checkboxes[r.id]}
                    r={r} />
            );
        })
    }

    toggle = (id, checked) => {
        this.setState({ checkboxes: { ...this.state.checkboxes, [id]: checked } })
    }
}
```

and your list item

```
class CheckboxListItem extends React.Component {

    //...

    state = {
        checked: false
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const { checked } = this.props
        this.setState({ checked })
    }

    onToggle = () => {
        const { r } = this.props
        const newChecked = !this.state.checked
        this.setState({ checked: newChecked }, () => {
            this.props.toggle(r.id, newChecked)
        })
    }

    render() {
        const { r } = this.props
        const { checked } = this.state
        return (
            <ListItem
                title={r.logDate}
                onPress={this.onToggle}
                subtitle={
                    <CheckBox
                        title={`start: ${r.startedAtOdometerReading} -> end: ${r.endedAtOdometerReading}`}
                        checked={checked}
                        onPress={this.onToggle}
                        onIconPress={this.onToggle}
                    />
                }
            />
        )
    }
}
```

Make sure you also refactor Checkbox to use `checked` prop in its state so that it gets updated when `checked` changes

Comment: Thanks. I will post the solution I ended up using below. I'm not sure why the state isn't persisting and perhaps your answer would have fixed it, but I didn't try it.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that the reason you get an empty array is because the list is unmounted, and its state is cleared.

Comment: The list isn't being unmounted

Answer (score 1):

I changed to an array of strings and it all works now. This solution also works better because I can setup a button to "check" all items in the list or "remove" them all by just adding all ids to the array, or removing them all.

```
{
  this.props.data.allLogs.map((r) => (
      <ListItem
        key={r.id}
        title={`${getReadableDate(r.logDate, true)}`}
        subtitle={
          <CheckBox
            title={`start: ${r.startedAtOdometerReading} -> end: ${r.endedAtOdometerReading}`}
            checked={this.state.checkboxes && this.state.checkboxes.includes(r.id)}
            onPress={() => this.toggle(r.id)}
            onIconPress={() => this.toggle(r.id)}
          />
        }
      />
  ))
}

  toggle(id) {
    let checkboxes = this.state.checkboxes;
    if(checkboxes && checkboxes.includes(id)){
      const index = checkboxes.indexOf(id);
      checkboxes.splice(index, 1);
    } else {
      checkboxes = checkboxes.concat(id);
    }
    this.setState({checkboxes});

  }
```